# gdb "info sources" shows wrong files

Tags: gdb, mingw

I compiled ffmpeg, and now I'm trying to run it in a debugger. But gdb can't find sources, I can't even set breakpoint at main because of that.

Look what output the `info sources` gives to me:

```
Source files for which symbols have been read in:
Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:
C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_lock.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/include/msvcrt.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/secapi/_localtime64_s.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/secapi/_gmtime64_s.c, C:/building/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/psdk_inc/intrin-impl.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/output_format.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/invalid_parameter_handler.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/wcsnlen.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/wcrtomb.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/strnlen.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/smisc.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gdtoaimp.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/misc.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/hexnan.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/hd_init.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gmisc.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gethex.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gdtoa.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/dmisc.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/log2l.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/internal_logl.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/exp2l.S, C:/building/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/math.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_pformat.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mbrtowc.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/powi.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/powi.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/sum.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/strtopx.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/strtof.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/strtodg.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/tanf.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/sinl_internal.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/sinf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/sin.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/sin.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/scalbn.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/pow.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/pow.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/log2f.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/log2.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/log.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/log.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/ldexp.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/fmod.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/floor.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/exp2f.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/exp2.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/exp.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/exp.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/cosl_internal.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/cosf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/cos.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/cos.c, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/ceilf.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/ceil.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/atanf.c, C:
/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/atan2.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/x86/atan2f.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/vsnprintf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_vsprintf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_vsnprintf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_vfscanf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_vfprintf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/lseek64.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/ftello64.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/fseeko64.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/wassert.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/strtoumax.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/strtoimax.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mkstemp.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mingw_matherr.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/gettimeofday.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mingw_getsp.S, C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\crt-x86_64-w64-mingw32/mingw_getsp.S, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/sqrt.def.h, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/sqrtf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/sqrt.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/s_erf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/roundf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/round.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/modf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/logf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/log10f.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/hypot.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/fabs.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/cbrtf.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/math/cbrt.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/strtodnrp.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/pesect.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/pseudo-reloc-list.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/tlsmcrt.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/tlsthrd.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt_handler.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/xtxtmode.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/pseudo-reloc.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/mingw_helpers.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/CRT_fp10.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/merr.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/cinitexe.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/tlssup.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/_newmode.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/gs_support.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/dllargv.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/charmax.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/wildcard.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/natstart.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/gccmain.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/atonexit.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/libsrc/guid_nul.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/libsrc/strmiids.c, C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c
```

I don't even have `C:/repo`, I keep files in `D:/_ffmpeg`. None of those files are related to ffmpeg, they all are from C runtime. I'm running `ffmpeg_g.exe`, which should have the debug info in it. I compiled it using this https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite

Edit1: Just tried `info functions main`, this is the output. Why a lot of them are marked as `Non-debugging symbols`.

```
(gdb) info functions main
All functions matching regular expression "main":

File C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:
int mainCRTStartup(void);
static int __tmainCRTStartup(void);

File C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/gccmain.c:
void __main(void);

Non-debugging symbols:
0x000000014005d020  config_input_main
0x00000001400784a0  config_input_main
0x00000001400d9580  config_input_main
0x000000014067f080  main_function
0x000000014067f2f0  ff_slice_thread_execute_with_mainfunc
0x0000000140bfa120  ff_aac_apply_main_pred
0x0000000140bfb7b0  ff_aac_encode_main_pred
0x0000000140db1d40  mainSort
0x0000000140dc2de0  find_domain_parms_idx
0x0000000140e24790  _gpg_w32_bindtextdomain
0x0000000140e24a70  _gpg_w32_textdomain
0x0000000141370af8  __getmainargs
0x0000000141371500  main
0x00000001413fc430  mainGtU.part.0
(gdb)
```

Comment: Did you generate debugging information when you compile it?? Did you compile with `-g` flag?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I don't know exact compile flags.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000141371500  main
```

means that your build does not have debug info, and without it GDB will *not* be able to perform any source-level debugging.

> I can't even set breakpoint at main because of that.

You are likely mistaken: GDB only needs to know the address (`0x141371500` above) in order to set a breakpoint on `main`.

> I don't know exact compile flags

Well, *you* have to *look* (we can't do that for you).

Once you've looked, you'll see that either `-g` is not present on compile line(s), or that the executable is stripped after compilation.

If it's the former, doing `make CFLAGS=-g` will probably fix this.

If it's the latter, you are probably debugging *installed* application. You may be able to debug *built* application instead (i.e. the binary before `make install`).

**Update:**

> Can I study what debug info is present, without looking at compiler flags?

Yes: `objdump -g ffmpeg_g.exe` should print it all. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html):

```
  -g
  --debugging
       Display debugging information.  This attempts to parse STABS and
       IEEE debugging format information stored in the file and print it
       out using a C like syntax.  If neither of these formats are found
       this option falls back on the -W option to print any DWARF
       information in the file.
```

Comment: Can I study what debug info is present, without looking at compiler flags?

Answer (score 0):

When you attach the process do you get any info like    "(no debugging symbols found)...done.You can try the     "rbreak" command without any expression. This should set breakpoints at each function of any given source file.